# React tab.find() as ternary condition in inline style

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, styles, inline, ternary

Got an error using a method as ternary condition in inline style of a div :

```
<div style={{display: tabHidden.findIndex(e=>e === item.name) > -1 ? 'none' : 'flex'}}>
```

A function push or splice the name of item from an array in a state `tabHidden`.
Here is the function call :

```
<Icon
  path={
    tabData.find((e) => e.name === item.name).orientation === "horizontal"
      ? mdiDominoMask
      : mdiEyeOutline
  }
  size={0.8}
  color="white"
  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
  onClick={() => toggleHide(item.name)}
/>;
```

And the function:

```
const toggleHide = (name) => {
    let arrCopy = [...tabHidden];
    console.log(arrCopy);
    let newTab;
    let index = tabHidden.findIndex((e) => e === name);
    console.log("index : ", index);
    if ((index = -1)) {
      newTab = arrCopy.push(name);
    } else {
      newTab = arrCopy.splice(index, 1);
    }
    setTabHidden(newTab);
};
```

Could you help me deal with this error:

> "tabHidden.findIndex is not a function"

It works in the inline style as the component is mounted, but when I click to launch the function, the error occurs.

**EDIT**

Ok so I did it that way, and it works (helped by a programming killer of course) :

```
const toggleHide = (name) => {
  let arrCopy = [...tabHidden];
  console.log(arrCopy);

  let index = arrCopy.findIndex((e) => e === name);
  console.log("index : ", index);
  if (index === -1) {
    arrCopy.push(name);
  } else {
    arrCopy.splice(index, 1);
  }
  setTabHidden(arrCopy);
};
```

Comment: did you debug what contains tabHidden before the crash ? seems like it is not an array, where is coming from exactly

Comment: That was exactly that : push() returns the length of the array, not an array :) Thank you very much !